# Fatal Exception: NSRangeException - index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

In one of the library that i use in a swift project, a line causes app to crash. I try to understand and fix it but no luck. I know that it is caused by an array index error. Anyone can help?

Crash Report

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x180a42e38 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1800a7f80 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x180922ebc -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]
3                          0x10000ac70 -[ChatSectionManager messageForIndexPath:] (ChatSectionManager.m:435)
4                          0x10001c194 -[Chat tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] (Chat.m:596)
5  UIKit                          0x185ee2f40 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:]
6  UIKit                          0x185ee30a8 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:willDisplay:]
```

**ChatSectionManager.m**

```
 - (QBChatMessage *)messageForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.item == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    QMChatSection *currentSection = self.chatSections[indexPath.section];
    //crashes here line 435
    return currentSection.messages[indexPath.item];
}
```

**Chat.m**

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.chatSectionManager messagesCountForSectionAtIndex:section];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.chatSectionManager.chatSectionsCount;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    QBChatMessage *messageItem = [self.chatSectionManager messageForIndexPath:indexPath];
```

... **Method that contains** `removeObjectAtIndex`

```
- (void)deleteMessages:(NSArray *)messages animated:(BOOL)animated {

    dispatch_async(_serialQueue, ^{

        NSMutableArray *messagesIDs = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSMutableArray *itemsIndexPaths = [NSMutableArray array];
        NSMutableIndexSet *sectionsIndexSet = [NSMutableIndexSet indexSet];

        self.editableSections = self.chatSections.mutableCopy;

        for (QBChatMessage *message in messages) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self indexPathForMessage:message];
            if (indexPath == nil) continue;

            QMChatSection *chatSection = self.chatSections[indexPath.section];
            [chatSection.messages removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

            if (chatSection.isEmpty) {
                [sectionsIndexSet addIndex:indexPath.section];
                [self.editableSections removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

                // no need to remove elements whose section will be removed
                NSArray *items = [itemsIndexPaths copy];
                for (NSIndexPath *index in items) {
                    if (index.section == indexPath.section) {
                        [itemsIndexPaths removeObject:index];
                    }
                }
            } else {

                [itemsIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
            }
        }

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            self.chatSections = self.editableSections.copy;
            self.editableSections = nil;

            if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(chatSectionManager:didDeleteMessagesWithIDs:atIndexPaths:withSectionsIndexSet:animated:)]) {

                [self.delegate chatSectionManager:self didDeleteMessagesWithIDs:messagesIDs atIndexPaths:itemsIndexPaths withSectionsIndexSet:sectionsIndexSet animated:animated];
            }
        });
    });
}
```

**NOTE**: This crash happens randomly and i don't know why

**FABRIC CRASH REPORT**
http://crashes.to/s/679e90f0c90

Comment: The code you posted doesn't match the stack trace. The crash shows you calling `removeObjectAtIndex:` on an `NSArray` from your `ChatSectionManager messageForIndexPath:` method on line 596. But the code you posted for `messageForIndexPath:` makes no call to `removeObjectAtIndex:`.

Comment: @maddy i posted what i have on xcode, is there anywhere else that i should check??

Comment: You basically posted the write info but for some reason it doesn't match. Did you change the implementation of `messageForIndexPath:`?

Comment: Nope i did not change anything, should i search for removeObjectAtIndex in those files?

Comment: There should be no need to search. The stack trace says you will find the call to `removeObjectAtIndex:` in ChatSectionManager.m on line 435. What code is actually at line 435?

Comment: this is the code at 435 -> return currentSection.messages[indexPath.item];

Comment: By the way i am getting this crash log from fabric

Comment: Looks like you are adding data to the datasource via a background thread?  If so, where is the thread synchronisation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely a problem with `deleteMessages`, look where your thread 16 is at the crash:

> QMChatSectionManager.m line 228
>   __48-[QMChatSectionManager deleteMessages:animated:]_block_invoke

Check which line 228 is exactly to know for sure what the problem is, but I'll go out on a limb here and guess it's

```
[chatSection.messages removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
```

so you're removing on thread 16 the data structure referenced on the main thread by `messageForIndexPath`. This, as you've noticed, is an open invitation to a race condition which is nigh on impossible to reproduce on demand.

The fix is to not modify the contents of `chatSection` in the background thread. Looks like you've already got the right idea where you assign the completed section list on the main thread,

```
self.chatSections = self.editableSections.copy;
```

just apply that logic to every item changed within the section list as well, and your random crashes will disappear.